# Eliminar un nodo/div - DOM - Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

Os pongo en situación.

Tengo un formulario con `id="miformulario"` en el cual existen 2 botones (`btnEnviar`, para enviar el formulario y mostrar en una caja/`div` ciertos elementos del formulario; y `btnEliminar`, para eliminar la caja/`div` que creamos previamente mediante el `btnEnviar`.

```
<input type="submit" value="Enviar" id="enviar" name="btnEnviar"/>
<input type="button" value="Eliminar" id="eliminar" name="btnEliminar"/>
```

El error es el siguiente: ¿Por qué si pulso btnEliminar, habiendo pulsado anteriormente btnEnviar para crear el div me muestra TODAS las veces el mensaje de alerta?

**Código JS/DOM para el botón btnEliminar:**

```
//Función para eliminar la caja resumen de los datos del formulario. DOM
//Inicializamos la variable "div" a null.
function eliminarCajaResumen(){
    //Si existe la caja o el div...
    var div = document.getElementById('div');
    if(div !== null){
        while (div.hasChildNodes()){
            div.removeChild(div.lastChild);
        }
    }else{
        alert ("No existe la caja previamente creada.");
    }
}
```

**Código JS/DOM para el botón btnEnviar:**

```
//Inicializamos la variable "div" a null.
var div = null;
//Función que crea una caja con los datos del resumen. Se debe crear usando DOM.
function crearCajaResumen(){
    //Si no hay ningun div...
    if(div == null){
        //Creamos el elemento/objeto que deseamos, sea <p> o <div> o <form>, etc.
        div = document.createElement("div");
        //DIV tiene la propiedad style, la cual permite acceder a atributos CSS. Ejemplo: div.style.width = "280px"; ...
        div.setAttribute("style", "width: 280px; height: 170px; background-color: #FE775A; position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 20px;");
        //Guardamos en una variable el body, aunque no haría falta, por cada HTML solo existe un body, entonces: "document.body".
        //var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
        //Guardamos en una variable el elemento/objeto que deseamos, <center>
        var center = document.getElementsByTagName("center")[0];
        //Insertamos el elemento "div" antes que el "center".
        document.body.insertBefore(div, center);
    }

    //Borramos los elementos que tenga la capa (previamente).
    while (div.hasChildNodes()) {
        div.removeChild(div.lastChild);
    }

    //Creamos un nodo de texto que agregaremos al div.
    var titulo = document.createTextNode("DATOS RESUMEN FORMULARIO:\n\n");
    //Añade un nuevo nodo al final de la lista.
    div.appendChild(titulo);

    //Declaramos un array donde guardaremos los textos seleccionados.
    var seleccionados = [];
    //Declaramos un array donde guardamos todos los elementos de tipo name=prefe.
    var preferencias = document.getElementsByName("prefe");
    //Recorremos ese array de elementos name=prefe.
    for(var i=0; preferencias[i]; ++i){
        //Si está marcada la casilla...
        if(preferencias[i].checked){
            //Agregamos al array "seleccionados" el valor de "preferencias[i]".
            seleccionados.push(preferencias[i].value); //push() --> añade elementos al final de un array en Javascript.
        }
    }

    //Añadimos un salto de línea.
    var saltolinea1 = document.createElement("br");
    div.appendChild(saltolinea1);

    //Recorremos el nuevo array "seleccionados".
    seleccionados.forEach(function(valor, index, array) {
        //Por cada "seleccionado", asignamos: salto de línea, la preferencia "p"; y ambas variables las añadimos al "div".
        var salto = document.createElement("br")
        var p = document.createTextNode(valor);
        div.appendChild(salto);
        div.appendChild(p);
    });

    //Añadimos saltos de línea.
    var saltolinea2 = document.createElement("br");
    div.appendChild(saltolinea2);
    var saltolinea3 = document.createElement("br");
    div.appendChild(saltolinea3);

    //Contamos los elementos que se han seleccionado.
    if(seleccionados.length==1)
        var contar = document.createTextNode("Has seleccionado " + seleccionados.length + " elemento."); // +contar_seleccionados()+
    else
        var contar = document.createTextNode("Has seleccionado " + seleccionados.length + " elementos."); // +contar_seleccionados()+

    //Creamos el elemento salto de línea (br). En HTML, <br/>.
    var salto = document.createElement("br");
    //Agregamos al "div" ambas variables.
    div.appendChild(contar);
    div.appendChild(salto);
}
```

**Llamada al evento:**

```
miformulario.btnEliminar.addEventListener("click", function(){ 
        return eliminarCajaResumen();
    }, false);
```

Comment: En tu método de crearCaja no veo en qué momento le asignas un id a tu `div` que estás creando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya que no colocaste un `id` a la `div` que creaste debes acceder a ella mediante `getElementsByTagName()`.

Ejemplo:

```
//Función para eliminar la caja resumen de los datos del formulario. DOM
//Inicializamos la variable "div" a null.
function eliminarCajaResumen(){
    //Si existe la caja o el div...
    var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
    if(div !== null){
        while (div.hasChildNodes()){
            div.removeChild(div.lastChild);
        }
    }else{
        alert ("No existe la caja previamente creada.");
    }
}
```

Aunque lo correcto seria crear la `div` con un `id`.

Ejemplo:

```
//Inicializamos la variable "div" a null.
var div = null;
//Función que crea una caja con los datos del resumen. Se debe crear usando DOM.
function crearCajaResumen(){
    //Si no hay ningun div...
    if(div == null){
        //Creamos el elemento/objeto que deseamos, sea <p> o <div> o <form>, etc.
        div = document.createElement("div");
        //DIV tiene la propiedad style, la cual permite acceder a atributos CSS. Ejemplo: div.style.width = "280px"; ...
        div.setAttribute("id", "container");
        div.setAttribute("style", "width: 280px; height: 170px; background-color: #FE775A; position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 20px;");
        //Guardamos en una variable el body, aunque no haría falta, por cada HTML solo existe un body, entonces: "document.body".
        //var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
        //Guardamos en una variable el elemento/objeto que deseamos, <center>
        var center = document.getElementsByTagName("center")[0];
        //Insertamos el elemento "div" antes que el "center".
        document.body.insertBefore(div, center);
    }
```

Y luego usar el `id` para acceder a la `div`.

Ejemplo:

```
//Función para eliminar la caja resumen de los datos del formulario. DOM
//Inicializamos la variable "div" a null.
function eliminarCajaResumen(){
    //Si existe la caja o el div...
    var div = document.getElementById('container')
    if(div !== null){
        while (div.hasChildNodes()){
            div.removeChild(div.lastChild);
        }
    }else{
        alert ("No existe la caja previamente creada.");
    }
}
```

He modificado la rutina para eliminar la `<div id="container">...</div>` en lugar de su contenido.

Ejemplo:

```
//Función para eliminar la caja resumen de los datos del formulario. DOM
//Inicializamos la variable "div" a null.
function eliminarCajaResumen(){
    //Si existe la caja o el div...
    var div = document.getElementById('container')
    if(div !== null){
        var parent = div.parentElement;
        parent.removeChild(div);
    }else{
        alert ("No existe la caja previamente creada.");
    }
}
```

Comment: El problema es que borra el CONTENIDO del div, no borra el DIV completo. Es decir, borra el texto del div/caja, no borra la caja (lo sé porque tiene un fondo de color rosa-marrón, y me aparece aún el cuadrado del div dibujado.

Comment: Entiendo, pero debes entender que eso es lo que hace tu programa, voy a modificar mi respuesta para que elimine la `div` en lugar de su contenido.