# Como eliminar un div creado a través de js usando createElement

Tags: javascript

Estoy creando un dado simple que cuando pulso un botón se crea unos div en forma de circulo dependiendo el numero me sale con el math.random , pero si quiero re usar el dado tendré los div anteriores y los recién creados haciendo que por ejemplo en la 2 tirada tenga mas div de los que debería.
Mi pregunta es,que debería hacer para que pueda eliminar los div viejos al general nuevos div
(he probado "removeChild e remove()" y me da error y me dice que o no es una función (usando remove()) o que mi padre objeto no es node )
Este es mi codigo:

```
  const btn = document.getElementById("btn")
const cara = document.getElementById("cara")
let numero = 0;
btn.addEventListener("click", function calculo(){
random()
cerebro()

})

function random(){
    let cal = Math.floor(Math.random()* 7)
    numero = cal
    console.log(numero)
}

function draw(numero1){
    numero1 = document.createElement("div")
    numero1.setAttribute("class", "numero")
    numero1.style.width = "30px";
    numero1.style.height = "30px";
    numero1.style.backgroundcolor = " black";
    numero1.style.borderradius = "100%";
    numero1.style.position = "absolute";
    numero1.style.top = "20px";
    numero1.style.left = "25px";
    cara.append(numero1);
}

function draw2(numero2){
    numero2 = document.createElement("div")
    numero2.setAttribute("class", "numero")
    numero2.style.width = "30px";
    numero2.style.height = "30px";
    numero2.style.backgroundcolor = " black";
    numero2.style.borderradius = "100%";
    numero2.style.position = "absolute";
    numero2.style.top = "145px";
    numero2.style.left = "150px";
    cara.append(numero2);
}

function draw3(numero3){
    numero3 = document.createElement("div")
    numero3.setAttribute("class", "numero")
    numero3.setAttribute("id", "numero3")
    numero3.style.width = "30px";
    numero3.style.height = "30px";
    numero3.style.backgroundcolor = " black";
    numero3.style.borderradius = "100%";
    numero3.style.position = "absolute";
    numero3.style.top = "80px";
    numero3.style.left = "90px";
    cara.append(numero3);
}
function draw4(numero4){
    let numero44 = document.createElement("div")
    numero44.setAttribute("class", "numero")
    numero4 = document.createElement("div")
    numero4.setAttribute("class", "numero")
    numero4.style.width = "30px";
    numero4.style.height = "30px";
    numero4.style.backgroundcolor = " black";
    numero4.style.borderradius = "100%";
    numero4.style.position = "absolute";
    numero4.style.top = "20px";
    numero4.style.left = "150px";
    numero44.style.position = "absolute";
    numero44.style.top = "145px";
    numero44.style.left = "25px";
    cara.append(numero4, numero44);
}
function draw6(){
    let numero6 = document.createElement("div")
    let numero66 = document.createElement("div")
    numero66.setAttribute("class", "numero")
    
    numero6 = document.createElement("div")
    numero6.setAttribute("class", "numero")
    numero6.style.width = "30px";
    numero6.style.height = "30px";
    numero6.style.backgroundcolor = " black";
    numero6.style.borderradius = "100%";
    numero6.style.position = "absolute";
    numero6.style.top = "80px";
    numero6.style.left = "150px";
    numero66.style.position = "absolute";
    numero66.style.top = "80px";
    numero66.style.left = "25px";
    cara.append(numero6, numero66);
}
function cerebro(){
    if(numero === 1){
        draw()
        
    }else if(numero === 2){
        draw2()
        draw()
    }else if(numero === 3){
        draw2()
        draw()
        draw3()
    }else if(numero === 4){
        draw()
        draw2()
        
        draw4()
    }else if(numero === 5){
        draw()
        draw2()
        draw3()
        draw4()
    }else if(numero === 6){
        draw()
        draw2()
        draw6()
        draw4()
        cara.removeChild(draw3)
       
       
    }
}
```

en el caso de 6 lo que me interesa es borrar el draw3 ya que es el punto central, que al salirme 6 no debería haber un punto central

cualquier ayuda o consejo se agradece

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de elemento es `cara`? Explica también qué pretendes hacer aquí: `cara.removeChild(draw3)`. Explica también por qué no usas una sola función para crear tus caras.

Comment: ¿Ya leíste [esta pregunta y su respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/71625)? ;)

Comment: ¿Has probado con definir el numero3 como global mediante, por ejemplo, `let numero3 = 0`, y despues eliminarlo con `numero3.remove()` en lugar del `cara.removeChild(draw3)`?  La verdad es que cada vez que lanzas el dado se agregan muchos divs sin borrar los anteriores de ningun modo, y eso no creo que sea lo que tu quieres. Quizas necesitas predefinir todas las caras (numeroX) antes y conforme hagas un drawX agregar pero eliminar las que no toquen, no se, lo he mirado a ciegas pues no tengo un dado que mostrar.

Comment: -A. cedano, el elemento cara simplemente el div que contiene todos los demás div, digamos así que es el div principal

Comment: -masterguru , el dado es muy simple, teniendo solo una cara, y al tocar el botón en la misma cara se crea x puntos dependiendo del numero que salga, pero si sale 5 y después 6 , pues como no se ha borrado el anterior numero habría 7 puntos en pantalla, Pues lo que yo quiero hacer es que cuando salga x numero me borre los puntos que no necesito

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Puedes eliminar todos los div con la misma clase de la siguiente forma:

```
function reset(){
    const elements = document.getElementsByClassName("numero");
    while(elements.length > 0){
        elements[0].parentNode.removeChild(elements[0]);
    }
}
```

getElementsByClassName busca todos los elementos con la misma clase (En este caso la clase "numero")

En javascript no hay forma directa de eliminar un elemento así que debes hacerlo a través del nodo que lo contiene (Parent)

Dentro del while se busca al nodo que contiene el elemento con la clase "numero" (Con parentNode) y se elimina. Ten en cuenta que dentro del while siempre se usa el índice 0 del arreglo ya que al eliminar el elemento con índice 0 el elemento que antes estaba en el índice 1 ahora pasa a ser el elemento con índice 0

Por ejemplo para un dado de 6 caras la siguiente línea de código devolveria un arreglo de 6 elementos (Desde elements[0] a elements[5])

```
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName("numero");
```

La siguiente línea elimina el primer elemento (elements[0]):

```
elements[0].parentNode.removeChild(elements[0]);
```

Entonces ahora nos quedan 5 elementos (Desde elements[1] a elements[5]) pero los índices se vuelven a asignar desde 0 por lo que en realidad tendríamos desde elements[0] a elements[4]. Es por esta razon que al escribir la línea de código anterior dentro de un while elimina todos los elementos con la misma clase hasta que el arreglo "elements" está vacío

Comment: E probado tu solución pero al ponerla en la función "principal" me elimina directamente todo siempre haciendo que nunca se cree los divs que necesito, no se si es por que lo aplico mal (que seguramente es mi culpa) o algo mas que no entiendo

Comment: ¿En qué parte estás ejecutando la función?

Comment: lo he puesto en la función calculo()

Comment: ¿Tienes algún jsfiddle donde pueda ver lo que estas haciendo?

Comment: No debes ejecutar la función todo el tiempo, reset debería ejecutarse únicamente cuando quieras borrar los div

Comment: llevo poco tiempo programando así que no tengo jsfiddle , pero creo que ya se el error y como solucionarlo, al usar remove.child en la function cerebro() lo que hace es que siempre este active pero si, por ejemplo me sale un 6 de primeras, me va a dar error eliminar el numero5 , por que no esta creado aun , y asi con todos los números, por eso tengo que crear otra function que funcione si ya hay divs creados (no se si me explico) gracias igualmente por la ayuda ya que me diste la idea de esto

Comment: jsfiddle es una plataforma gratuita donde puedes poner tu código html, js y css para ejecutarlo y haver pruebas (https://jsfiddle.net/). Podrías intentar ejecutar reset() justo antes de crear cada número, así eliminaría el número anterior. Si lo pones dentro de calculo podrías intentar poniéndolo antes que las otras funciones

Comment: vale si ese era mi error, funciona ahora, gracias